# Is it legal to say I live at another address to Medi-Cal?

Tags: california, medical

My wife and I got a house that we were told was still in the same county. Turns out only the mailbox is, but sone. Since the house is in another county we're being forced to change Medi-Cal plans, this change is extremely harmful to us.

My in-laws live not far and if our address was there we'd be able to pick a better plan. I'd rather not move again so I was wondering if we could tell Medi-Cal that we lived with the in-laws and get the better plans without physically moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a false statement to claim to live in one county when you actually live in a different one. It becomes perjury (a crime) when you falsely swear to that statement on your [status report](https://www.dhcs.ca.gov/formsandpubs/forms/Forms/MC176S_ENG_0309.pdf), and you are required to report changes in "household situation" within 10 days. There isn't an exception allowing you to give a false address "in case it costs more to report truthfully". The only legal solutions are to report truthfully and pay more, or move again, report truthfully, and not pay more.